# Why does Djinn fail to realize common monadic functions?

Tags: haskell, types

I recently stumbled across [Djinn](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/djinn) and was briefly playing around with it to try to see whether it would be useful in my everyday coding workflow. I was excited to see that Djinn had monads and tried to see whether it might be able to find some cool functions.

Djinn did in fact work some wonders. The type signature of the initially (at least to me) unintuitive function `>>= (>>=)` is `Monad m => ((a -> m b) -> m a) -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Djinn was able to immediately demystify this by stating

```
Djinn> f ? Monad m => ((a -> m b) -> m a) -> (a -> m b) -> m b
f :: (Monad m) => ((a -> m b) -> m a) -> (a -> m b) -> m b
f a b = a b >>= b
```

Unfortunately, Djinn can't seem to find other standard functions on monads, despite knowing about the Monad typeclass.

- `join` (which should be `join = (>>= id)` or in Djinn's more verbose syntax `join a = a >>= (\x -> x)`)

  ```
  Djinn> join ? Monad m => m (m a) -> m a
  -- join cannot be realized.
  ```
- `liftM` (which should be `liftM f = (>>= (return . f))` or in Djinn's more verbose syntax `liftM a b = b >>= (\x -> return (a x))`)

  ```
  Djinn> liftM ? Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b
  -- liftM cannot be realized.
  ```
- Even the basic `return :: Monad m => m a -> m (m a)` cannot be found by Djinn or `return :: Monad m => (a, b) -> m (a, b)`.

  ```
  Djinn> f ? Monad m => (a, b) -> m (a, b)
  -- f cannot be realized.
  ```

Djinn knows how to use `\` to construct anonymous functions so why is this the case?

My rough suspicion is that perhaps Djinn has a simplistic notion of typeclass and somehow treats `m a` as "fixed" so that `m (a, b)` is not seen as a case of `m a`, but I have no idea how to make that any more concrete than its current hand-wavy form or whether that intuition is correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Supporting type classes properly looks a lot like supporting rank-2 types; compare:

```
join :: Monad m
     => m (m a) -> m a
```

vs:

```
join :: (forall a. a -> m a)
     -> (forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b)
     -> m (m a) -> m a
```

Unfortunately, the techniques Djinn uses don't handle rank-2 types at all. If you float the foralls so that Djinn can process it, suddenly what you get instead are *concrete* choices:

```
join :: (b -> m b)
     -> (m c -> (c -> m d) -> m d)
     -> m (m a) -> m a
```

which looks a lot less like you could implement it! If you tell Djinn which instantiations to use, it does a lot better, of course.

```
join :: (b -> m b)
     -> (m (m a) -> (m a -> m a) -> m a)
     -> m (m a) -> m a
```

For this one, Djinn will give the right implementation. ...but then, that's cheating.

Comment: That relationship between typeclasses and rank-2 types is pretty cool; I'd never thought of it before. I can see that supporting higher ranked types probably leads you into needing to build a theorem prover for general first order logic, which seems very hard to get practical results and undecidable in general. Is that necessary though to fully support typeclasses? How does Djinn currently deal with typeclasses and could it be extended?

Comment: Or to state my follow-up question more clearly, it seems clear that being able to deal with rank-2 types is sufficient to deal with typeclasses but is it necessary?

Comment: @badcook I think it wouldn't be hard to turn a Djinn that deals with typeclasses correctly into a Djinn that handles rank-2 types by generating a fresh typeclass for the function arguments that make the type rank-2. Of course, the devil is in the details, and I haven't worked out the details, so I don't know for sure.